# Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'

Tags: angular, observable, angular7, type-mismatch

I have an error:
 Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
  Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

```
  deleteUser(userId: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.httpClient
      .delete(url, this.getHttpOptions())
      .map(res => {
        return res;
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

I got the type of res as a boolean when I tried to print it.

Comment: Try that: `return this.httpClient.delete<boolean>(...)`, and you won't need the `map`

Comment: This error should be thrown from different place. Check the code where you are using this deleteUser method. And make sure you have set Observable<boolean> in there too; Or you can try .delete<boolean>(url, this.getHttpOptions()); This should work too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At compile time, TypeScript doesn't know what actually comes from API call, it infers it from declarations and function signatures.

```
      .delete<boolean>(url, this.getHttpOptions())
```

should work.

(And yes, ditch the `map`).

Answer (score 1):

The type of `res` needs to be `boolean`, by default it will be `any`.  Replace map by following :

```
map((res:boolean) => {
    return res;
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by removing your `.map` (which doesn't do anything):

```
deleteUser(userId: string): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.httpClient
    .delete(url, this.getHttpOptions())
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```